# Raspberry Pi JDK7

Tags: java

I am very new to Raspberry PI. I noticed that you could get anything on Raspberry PI including Java. So using this command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk
```

I installed JDK 7 on my Raspberry PI.

The problem is, I don't know how to compile. I opened the `leaf` editor, wrote the usual HelloWorld code in it and saved it as `HelloWorld.java`. However, from there I was stuck. How do I compile this?

Answer (score 2):

To compile a java program use javac. It should be installed already. You can double check by using `javac -version`.

Once installed, use command `javac 'filename'` to compile. And the class file will be output in the same directory.

You can then use the command `java` to execute the class.

Comment: I tried javac Hello.java however, it keeps saying javac: file not found error.

Comment: You will need to make sure that bash is in the same directory as the file location before using javac. Otherwise try using the full file path e.g. `c:/usr/home/Desktop/myfile`

Comment: @Steven your question says the file name is `HelloWorld.java`, so trying to compile `Hello.java` would naturally result in a `file not found error`.